# Calculating Pandas Means from Row Numbers Given in Nested Numpy Array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I've been stuck on this problem for quite some time now and couldn't find anything similar, so I'd appreciate some hints. I have two DataFrames; `df1` with ~1,200,000 rows and `df2` with ~500 rows. For each of the 500 rows in `df2` I have a set of row numbers, corresponding to values in `df1`, stored in a numpy array. For each row I'd like to calculate the mean of `df1` from the indicated row numbers, and add it to `df2`.
Here's an example, assuming that `df2` only has three rows.

```
some_array = np.array([102, 562, 132467, 4345, 122],
                      [53693, 562, 333, 6454, 2456],
                      [102, 562, 132467, 1666, 222])
```

So for each row in `some_array` I want to calculate the set of means of `df1` using the specified row numbers. So in this case the first row of `df2` would be

```
df2.iloc[0] = df1.iloc[some_array[0]].mean()
```

but for all rows in `some_array`. I can easily solve this with an iterative approach, but it is unfortunately too slow. I can't really wrap my head around faster approaches.

Any help would be appreciated, and I hope the question is clear!

Comment: When you say this refers to row numbers in df1, do you mean that for example in `some_array` first row, you want the mean of a certain column's values at those rows? Or the mean of means of all values on those rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can do something like this:

```
some_array = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
                      [0,1,2,3],
                      [2,3,4,5]])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(18).reshape(6,-1))

groups = np.repeat(np.arange(some_array.shape[0]), some_array.shape[1])

df.iloc[some_array.ravel()].groupby(groups).apply(lambda x: x.mean(1))
```

Output:

```
0  1     4.0
   2     7.0
   3    10.0
   4    13.0
1  0     1.0
   1     4.0
   2     7.0
   3    10.0
2  2     7.0
   3    10.0
   4    13.0
   5    16.0
dtype: float64
```

Or if you don't need to keep the original row number in `some_array`, you can do:

```
(df.iloc[some_array.ravel()]
   .groupby(groups)
   .apply(lambda x: x.mean(1).reset_index(drop=True))
)
```

Output:

```
     0     1     2     3
0  4.0   7.0  10.0  13.0
1  1.0   4.0   7.0  10.0
2  7.0  10.0  13.0  16.0
```

Comment: Ahh nice solution with the groupby. This is exactly what I need - Thanks!